# Registration free COM interop. assembly B reference assembly A?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, delphi, typelib

[#import Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) is used in C++ to import a Type Library. 
"**no_registry**" attribute Tells the compiler not to search the registry for type libraries.

Ex:

```
#import "XXX.tlb" no_namespace named_guids no_registry
```

Quastion: 
I want to do the exact same thing in delphi:
I know [TLIBIMP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/TLIBIMP.EXE) is used, but i can not find any attribute like `no_registry`.

Ex:

```
TLIBIMP "XXX.tlb" ????
```

How is this done, or is this even possible?

**UPDATE:**

I have a Side-by side Side-by-side Assemblies.
An `COM` assembly(B) that references a `COM` assembly(A).
the error might be in the manifest file.
How can I define a dependency in the manifest?
How can i use `Tlbexp.exe` to define the dependency?
I have already tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<asmv1:assembly
 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
 xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
 xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  manifestVersion="1.0">
   <assemblyIdentity
     type="win32"
     name="CommonInteropB"
     version="1.0.0.0"
     publicKeyToken="" />

   <clrClass
   clsid="{XXXXXXXXX}"
   progid="CommonInteropB.SomeFactory"
    name="CommonInteropB.SomeFactory"
   threadingModel="Both" tlbid="{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}"
    runtimeVersion="v4.0.30319" />

  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                    name="CommonInteropA"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
                    publicKeyToken="" />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

</asmv1:assembly>
```

and to create the type library:

```
tlbexp.exe CommonInteropB.dll /tlbreference:"CommonInteropA.tlb" /tlbreference:"C:\Windows\System32\stdole2.tlb" /tlbreference:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb" /out:CommonInteropB.tlb
```

Comment: I don't see any option for TLIBIMP that will do so. You can import them in the IDE (Component->Import Component->Import Type Library, and then the Add button on the next page), but I don't know of any way to do so on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest looks fine. The dependency is specified by the **dependency** element.

tlibimp seems to check for dependencies in the registry and in the working directory (although I can find no documentation for this). If your setup requires side-by-side execution and you want to avoid registering your DLLs, make sure both assembly A and assembly B reside in the working directory and run `tlibimp B.tlb [options]`.